# session storage not able to save in reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, redux, session-storage

I have created a simple react app. But, I'm not able to save my session storage.

Here is my code below:

Main.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Popper from 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from "./components/topNavigation";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Banner from "./components/Banner";
import PLPMenu from "./components/PLPMenu";
import PDP from "./components/PDP";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import CartList from "./components/CartList";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {login} from "./actions";


class Main extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.login;
        console.log(this.props)
    }



     login() {
        // for all items in state
        for (let WCToken in this.props.login()) {
          // if the key exists in localStorage
          if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(WCToken)) {
            // get the key's value from localStorage
            let value = localStorage.getItem(WCToken);

            // parse the localStorage string and setState
            try {
              value = JSON.parse(value);
              this.setState({ [WCToken]: value });
            } catch (e) {
              // handle empty string
              this.setState({ [WCToken]: value });
            }
          }
        }
      }


    render() {


        return (
            <div>
                <button className=" float-right" onClick={(e) => this.props.login()}>Login in as Guest</button>

        <Navigation />

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/Apparel/:category/:subCategory/:id" component={PLPMenu}/>
                    <Route path="/Apparel/:product/:id" component={PDP}/>
                    <Route path="/cart" component={CartList}/>
                    <Route path="/Banner" component={Banner}/>
                    <Route path="/Footer" component={Footer}/>
                </Switch>


            </div>

        )

    }


}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loginResponse: state.fashion.loginResponse
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        login: login
    }, dispatch)
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

As you can see from my code above, I have created a button. On clicking on that button, I'm getting the response as below.

[image]

But, I need to save particularly, the two keys **WCToken** and **WCTrustedToken** in my session storage. Can anybody help me on this. I don't where my code is getting wrong. Or if someone could provide me an insight I would be grateful.

Comment: Did you post a picture of a console log? There is not console log in any of your posted code and I don't see any code of you saving the response to local storage.

Comment: That's what I'm unable to do. I posted the picture of console.log and I'm not able to map the response. I have written the code for session storage. It is right or wrong I don't know. Will you help me a little

Comment: You can see in my code above, I have created a buton. On clicking of it, I'm getting the response in the console browser window. Then I did component did mount and it's not working

Comment: You have a `Main.prototype.login` function that's never called in the code you provided and a login imported from `./actions` that is called in `componentDidMount` and when you click the button.

Comment: I have changed my code and also updated the console.log browser screenshot. Will you take a look now

Comment: You should study how redux works. You're trying to set `WCToken` to the result of a connected action creator function `this.props.login`. What `this.props.login` does we still don't know because it's missing from your question. My guess it's a function that redux-thunk will execute with a dispatch so you can dispatch an action with the results and reduce that into your state. Or at least that is how you should have done it if you used thunk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183114/discussion-between-sajjad-tabreez-and-hmr).